# Can we compare the arithmetic mean of the ratios given the comparison between individual arithmetic means?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, means

I have positive real random numbers $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ and $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ and $y_1,\ldots,y_n$.

I know that the arithmetic mean of $u_i$'s is greater than the arithmetic mean of $x_i$'s, i.e., $$\sum_{i=1}^nu_i\geq\sum_{i=1}^nx_i,$$ and
the arithmetic mean of $v_i$'s is less than the arithmetic mean of $y_i$'s, i.e.,
$$\sum_{i=1}^nv_i\leq\sum_{i=1}^ny_i.$$

When we can say that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{u_i}{v_i}\leq\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{x_i}{y_i}?$$ because intuitively it seems that the opposite inequality should hold but that is not true (I cannot find a **counterexample** though).
Can we say something for large $n$?

Comment: I don't like this use of "intuitively".  Can you *prove* it?  Can you transform your intuition into a rigorous argument?

Comment: Hint: Take equality in the first two equations. Then, if the final expression isn't equal (which is almost always isn't), then you can define $u, v, x, y$ accordingly to create a counter example. $\quad$ EG $1/10 + 10/1 >  1/1 + 10/10$ which creates a huge difference. $\quad$ This "symmetry resulting in a huge difference" tells you that "when can we say that ..." is going to require a lot of (absurd) conditions to try and bound a bunch of things.

Comment: I think a good way to understand what's going on is to solve the optimization problems
$$
\min_{\sum a_i=A,\sum b_i=B} \sum \frac{a_i}{b_i},\max_{\sum a_i=A,\sum b_i=B} \sum \frac{a_i}{b_i}
$$

This will give you insights (as function of the arithmetic means) to the maximal and minimal value your RHS and LHS are getting, and then you can figure out if for some $A_1 \le A_2$ and $B_1 \le B_2$ you can the desired behavior.

Comment: Intuitively, this is exactly what is going on - you want to decrease the sum of $\frac{u_i}{v_i}$, which requires you to increase $v_i$ but keeping the sum constant, so decreasing other $v_i$'s, and the decision which to increase and which to decrease lays over the $u_i$'s, the optimization problem captures that nature.

Comment: For a counter e.g., consider scaling up all the $u_i$ by some factor $k>1$, and scaling down every $v_i$ by $1/k$.  The sum inequalities remain valid, while the LHS of your target inequality is scaled up by $k^2$. So for a large enough $k$, you can always violate this.